# GWT: How do I remove the focus indicator of a Canvas Widget?

Tags: gwt, canvas, focus, html5-canvas

I have created a `Canvas` using:

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
```

and added it to the DOM via:

```
RootPanel.get("canvasContainer").add(canvas);
```

When I open up the page in Chrome and click it, it highlights with an orange focus border. In the Android browser, when touching the canvas, the entire canvas is highlighted with a semitransparent blue overlay, as well as a solid blue border, as if the canvas was selected.

How do I change this behavior, so that the canvas isn't highlighted in any way when clicked/touched?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add

```css
canvas {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); /* mobile webkit */
}
```

into your canvas tag CSS.

Comment: This does the trick for e.g. Chrome, but has no effect in the Android browser.

Comment: @claesv for android webkit, use `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); `

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work, try a hard refresh so that the CSS reloads too.

Comment: Worked for electron.js. Regular chrome was fine, but electron.js was outlining my focused canvas element.